# How to get a customized counter in enumerate environments and how to label and refer to the items?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

In my enumerate environments, I want to have something like `\myitem` which automatically prints `3(a).`, `3(b).` etc. (and of course, the regular `\item`s which still print the regular `1.`, `2.`, etc.)
BTW, I also would like to be able to label and refer (with clickable feature) to any kind of the two counters. In short, I want to type

```
‎\item‎‎ ‎foo‎‎
‎\item\label{itm1}‎‎ ‎bar‎‎
‎\myitem Something
‎\myitem\label{myitm3b} ‎Something‎‎ ‎else‎‎‎
‎\item‎ ‎foobar‎‎  
Let's refer to \ref{itm1} and \ref{myitm3b} to ...
```

and get

```
     1. foo
     2. ‎bar‎‎
  3(a). Something‎‎  
  3(b). Something‎‎ ‎else‎
 ‎    ‎4.‎ foobar‎‎  
     Let's refer to 1. and 3(b). to ...
```

I found similar questions on this website, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Would the answer to this question help you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60927/custom-enumeration-for-axioms-or-hypothesis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define `\myitem` to use a custom counter for the second part of the label:

[image]

### Notes:

- Contiguous use of `\myitem` will result in subsequent alphabetic characters, and any use of the regular `\item` will reset the next use of `\myitem` to start at `(a)`, as illustrated by `5(a)` in the test case below.
- As per **Heiko Oberdiek's** suggestion I used `\refstepcounter` counter instead of `\stepcounter` so as to provide anchors for use with [the `hyperref` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/).
- Much thanks to **T. Verron** for providing a link to [Custom enumeration for axioms or hypothesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60927/custom-enumeration-for-axioms-or-hypothesis) for the missing piece I was missing which was how to set up the custom label when the `\myitem` was referenced via a `\ref`.
- I use [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem)[the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) for list processing, but this solution should be adaptable to not require that if so desired.
- I have used `newtoggle` from [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) as I prefer that syntax versus the `\newif` syntax. But if you don't want to include an additional package it should be pretty straightforward to adapt this to use `\newif` or [some other conditional methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/33577#33577).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}% For hyperref testing.

\newcounter{MyCounter}
\newtoggle{AlreadyInMyItem}

\let\OldItem\item
\def\item{%
    \global\togglefalse{AlreadyInMyItem}%
    \setcounter{MyCounter}{0}%
    \OldItem%
}

\makeatletter
\def\myitem{%
    \OldItem[%
        \iftoggle{AlreadyInMyItem}{}{%
            \stepcounter{enumi}%
            \global\toggletrue{AlreadyInMyItem}%
        }%
        \refstepcounter{MyCounter}\theenumi%
        (\alph{MyCounter}).]%
         % Use "\protected@edef" here as per David Carlisle as it is safer
        \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\theenumi(\alph{MyCounter})}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=right]
    \item‎‎ ‎foo‎‎
    ‎\item\label{itm1}‎‎ ‎bar‎‎
    ‎\myitem Something
    ‎\myitem\label{myitm3b} ‎Something‎‎ ‎else‎‎‎
    ‎\item‎ ‎foobar‎‎  
    ‎\myitem Something
    ‎\myitem\label{myitm5b} ‎Something‎‎ ‎else‎‎‎
\end{enumerate}
%\clearpage% For hyperref testing.
Let's refer to \ref{itm1} and \ref{myitm3b}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: For `hyperref` support: `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter` also generates an anchor name and sets an anchor at the location of `\refstepcounter`. Also `\theH<counter>` with unique values should be provided to get unique anchor names.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Thanks. Have updated to use `\refstepcounter`.

Comment: I would put `\refstepcounter{MyCounter}` before `\theenumi` and using `\stepcounter{enumi}`. The latter avoids duplicate destination names and it cannot be references anyway, because of the next `\refstepcounter`. Also `\theMyCounter` could be redefined, making the definition of `\@currentlabel` obsolete.

Comment: @Peter: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for, but I'm currently curious to know how `\newif` can be replaced with the `newtoggle` from the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan: The toggle is just as boolean switch used to keep track of whether we are `AlreadyInMyItem`. It is set to true once we enter `\myitem`, and set to false once we enter a `\item`. Hence the sub enumeration can use the desired letters, and reset for a subsequent use. Please see [Conditional typesetting / build](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build) for details of other conditionals you can use. If that does not answer your question I would suggest posting a follow up question: "How to replace a `\newtoggle` with a `\newif`"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution with `\newif` boolean.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{vdcount}
\newif\ifvdam
\let\origitem\item
\def\item{%
  \global\vdamfalse
  \setcounter{vdcount}{0}%
  \origitem
}
\def\fancyitem{%
  \origitem[%
    \ifvdam\else
      \stepcounter{enumi}%
      \global\vdamtrue
    \fi
    \refstepcounter{vdcount}%
    \theenumi(\alph{vdcount}).%
  ]%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\theenumi(\alph{vdcount})}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=right]
  \item foo.
  \item\label{itm1} bar.
  \fancyitem Something.
  \fancyitem\label{myitm3b} Something else.
  \item foobar.
  \fancyitem Something.
  \fancyitem\label{myitm5b} Something else.
\end{enumerate}

Referring to items~\ref{itm1} and \ref{myitm3b}.
\end{document}
```