# Indent itemized list with custom item names

Tags: lists, indentation

How would I reproduce the typesetting in the screenshot below? In particular, I'm interested in the nicely indented list of hypotheses with the following features:

- The item names (H1, H2, H3) don't hang off into the left margin.
- The bodies of the three list items are aligned with each other and inset from the rest of the text

[image: A nicely indented list of hypotheses]

Comment: Package `enumitem` is your friend here, I think

Comment: Related: [Custom enumeration for axioms or hypothesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60927/5764)

Answer (score 3):

It's easy with the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[label=H\arabic*. , wide=0.5em,  leftmargin=*]
  \item \lipsum[2]
  \item \lipsum[3]
  \item \lipsum[4]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The package `enumitem` supports this out of the box, the only change required is the `label`, using `label={H\arabic*.}` as an option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{Hypotheses and Hypotenuses}
\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}[font={\bfseries},label={H\arabic*.}]
\item \blindtext
\item \blindtext
\item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]